# Batch script for add a auto-increased primary key for exist table with records

Tags: oracle, batch-file, primary-key

I have lots of tables in oracle, but none of them have a primary key.

And what is more, our application have been deployed to the client server with offline model.

Now we wonder if we can build a patch to update the tables without change the exist records:

1) Add primary key for each table(like `id`).

2) make this primary key auto-increasement.

3) update the tables to fill the primary key column.

So I wonder if I can create a batch script to do the above jobs, then I can send it to our clients to do the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the column and then populate it with unique values before making it the primary key. This answer shows how to do that with [sequences](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm), which is how you do auto-incrementing values in Oracle.

1. Add the column that will be the primary key (it can't be set to primary key yet). This example defines the column as `NUMBER(12)`, which along with a sequence of natural numbers gives you 10^12 - 1 possible key values. If you think you'll need more or less just adjust the column size accordingly.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myTableID NUMBER(12);
   ```
2. Create an Oracle `SEQUENCE`, which is used to generate unique values. I generally name sequences by appending `Seq` to the name of the table they'll generate values for; you should name them as you like. This sequence will start at the value 1 (`START WITH 1`) and because no increment is defined it will increment by 1.

   ```
   CREATE SEQUENCE myTableSeq START WITH 1;
   ```
3. Update the new column with values from the sequence. This will assign unique values to every row:

   ```
   UPDATE myTable SET myTableID = myTableSeq.NEXTVAL;
   ```
4. Now that the column has values it can be designated as the primary key (before step 3, designating it as the primary key would have failed because all its values were null and therefore not unique):

   ```
   ALTER TABLE myTable ADD PRIMARY KEY (myTableID);
   ```
5. Steps 1-4 take care of existing rows. Add a [trigger](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm) to automatically set the key value for future rows:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER myTablePKSet
   BEFORE INSERT ON myTable
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
     :NEW.myTableID := myTableSeq.NEXTVAL;
   END;
   /
   ```

Put all the commands shown above (in order) into a script and you'll have the fix for the `myTable` table. Repeat as needed for the remaining tables.

And in the future, implement primary keys from the beginning. It's very rare for a table to *not* have a primary key, and it's a very advanced skill to know when a table doesn't need one. Your safest bet is to *always* have a primary key.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.  But I wonder If I can save all those commands to a batch script, and run it? The window command line will not regonize the oracle commands.

Comment: You can save the commands to a script, and you should so you can test it first on your own copies of the tables. The convention is to name the script with a `.sql` extension, for example `AddPK.sql`. As for running the script: (1) copy it to your client's machine, (2) type `sqlplus username@servername/password` at the Windows Command Line, and (3) once you get the `SQL>` prompt type the at sign (`@`) followed by the location and name of the script as saved on the client machine, for example `@c:\temp\AddPK.sql`.

Comment: One more thing, since I have lots of tables, so I need to loop all the tables. So I wonder if this is possible?

Comment: It is, but you'd have to read from the data dictionaries and generate the script, then run it. That's pretty complicated and it would take a long time to write and test. Unless you have hundreds of tables you're better off doing this manually; just repeat the steps above for each of the tables. You can put everything into a single script. It'll definitely be tedious, but you'll only have to do it the one time.

Comment: One more thing - make sure to put the slash (`/`) from step 5 at the end of every trigger definition. Hard to explain why, but you'll need it.

Comment: Unfortunately, we have 80+ tables.

Comment: Ouch. Do you have a text editor with a macro facility? You could start with a list of table names and use a macro to expand them into the commands. Not pretty, but unfortunately this won't be pretty no matter how you do it.